# Thread not releasing jdbc connection in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, threadpool, hikaricp

We have a spring boot application whose starting point is an API. The API calls an interface say ITradeService which implements Callable. The ITradeService has a method service() which calls 7 methods in turn out of which the last three say method5() method6() and method7() are independent.

In the SIT,UAT environment for some reasons out of 4 nodes only one node is active and my project lead asked me to use 4 threads - 1 thread to execute the service method and other 3 threads to execute the above said 3 methods.

We have these three layers in our project

- Controller(Rest API)
- Service ITradeService
  TradeServiceImpl
  Type1TradeServiceImpl
  Type2TradeServiceImpl
  Type3TradeServiceImpl
- DAO     CommonDao    Type1Dao    Type2Dao    Type3Dao

We use JdbcTemplate in each of our DAO classes.

In our application.yaml we have configured the hikari database connection pool as 2

When i tried to execute the threads using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for 4 requests the process is working as expected but when i send the 5th request it is saying

CannotCreateTransactionException Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction

I understand that the 4 threads are holding the JDBC Connection.
I should make the threads release the JDBC connection and send it back to the hikari connection pool
or
i should close the threads upon task completion

How should i do it in a spring specific way?

Comment: 'project lead asked me to use 4 threads - 1 thread to execute the service method and other 3 threads to execute the above said 3 methods' - what is the rationale behind this request? It is generally a good idea to keep methods corresponding to a single unit of work on the same thread, as transactions do not span multiple threads. Please describe the actual use case a little better, then perhaps we might help

Comment: the 3 methods take a common input and sends messages to different queues .

Comment: Fair enough, but why does the enqueuing need to happen asynchronously? Couldn't those three methods just run serially?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to understand *why* you feel you need to run those three methods in parallel.

In any case, you can solve/mitigate the issue by:

- setting the [appropriate `connectionTimeout`, and `maximumPoolSize`](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#essentials) to make sure either the pool autoscales to meet the application demand, or the additional threads do not timeout while waiting for the connection to be released, and/or
- making sure the time the connection is open during the execution of those three methods is as short as possible, e.g. the thread is not doing heavy calculations, file access etc. within a `@Transactional` method.

Regarding the second bullet point, if you absolutely need the operations to be atomic, perhaps you could use optimistic locking (pull out the information you need and finish the unit of work there, do the heavylifting on a detached copy of the data, initiate another unit of work, see if the data changed in the meantime, and if so, retry the whole process, otherwise just update the data with your copy).